# Can I have a function with return type of the class itself in inherited classes? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I have a parent class that is also a factory. For example:

```
Public Class Factory
    Public Function clone() as Factory
        ' Some logic here
        ' return something
    End Function

    Public Function all() as List (Of Factory)
        ' Some logic here
        ' return something
    End Function
End Class
```

And then an inherited one

```
Public Class BookFactory
    inherits Factory
End Class
```

I can use inflection in the Factory class to generate the proper extended objects when called by the inherited one. `myBookFactory.clone()` will then return a `BookFactory` instance and not only a `Factory` instance.

The problem: this `BookFactory` instance will be cast as `Factory`, since the type of the function is `Factory` and not `BookFactory`.

I'd like to do something like

```
Public Class Factory
    Public Function clone() as Me.GetType()
        ' Some logic here
        ' return something
    End Function

    Public Function all() as List (Of  Me.GetType())
        ' Some logic here
        ' return something
    End Function
End Class
```

So the returned value would be correctly cast and avoid having to do this each time:

```
Dim myBookFactory2 = DirectCast(myBookFactory1.clone(), myBookFactory1.getType())
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You are seriously murdering the factory pattern here.  But no, cast required if the consumer cares about the derived type.  Which it should not. Compare to XmlWriter.Create() in the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a variation on asking for covariant return types.  As you have noticed, this is not supported by VB.NET (or C# for that matter).  Typically this is asked in the context of overriding virtual methods, where it is still not allowed.  There are several alternatives, each with their own pros and cons.

**Use a generic template argument to specify the derived class**

This is similar to the way `IComparable<T>` is most commonly implemented.

```
Public Class Factory(Of T As Factory)
    Public Function Clone() As T
        'use GetType(T) to determine derived type
    End Function
End Class

Public Class BookFactory
    Inherits Factory(Of BookFactory)
End Class
```

Additionally, if you can add a `New` constraint to the Factory (eg: `Factory(Of T {New, Factory(Of T)})`) base class, you may be able to avoid using reflection.

However, this does not prevent the accidental (or potentially malicious) mistake of declaring a class like this:

```
Public Class EvilFactory
    Inherits Factory(Of BookFactory)
    'hmmm, now clone will be making the wrong type
End Class
```

Also, this approach makes it impossible to create a list of factories of different types without resorting to another base class below `Factory(Of T)` or declaring the list as being of object.

**Make new methods on the derived classes that return the specific type you want.**

```
Public Class Factory
    Public Function Clone() As Factory
        'create derived class, but return as base
    End Function
End Class

Public Class BookFactory
    Inherits Factory

    Public Function CloneBooks() As BookFactory
        Return CType(Me.Clone(), BookFactory)
    End Function
End Class
```

This allows you to hide the cast for those times when you know you have a `BookFactory` and want to get another `BookFactory`.  It also lets you treat all factory types polymorphically in the normal inheritance sense.  However, if you have an object typed as `Factory`, you will still get back an object type as `Factory`.

**Reconsider the inheritance relationship**

Depending on how these classes are used, it may not make sense to use the inheritance relationship here.  If you are only concerned with not retyping code, you may want to look into code generation instead.

Comment: I wanted to make the second class as short as possible, without the overloads if possible. Your answers is clear and helpful, thank you. I'll also check code generation, never used it.

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially use generics to make the problem easier, but it won't remove the requirement to cast at some point. For example:

```
Public Class Factory(Of T)
    Public Function clone() As Factory(Of T)
        ' Some logic here
        ' return something
    End Function

    Public Function all() As Collections.Generic.List(Of T)
        ' Some logic here
        ' return something
    End Function
End Class

Public Class BookFactory
    Inherits Factory(Of Book)

End Class
```